# How to pass a pathname with a space in it to cd inside of a script

Tags: bash, scripts

I am working on Windows 10 and am using the Ubuntu subsystem. Often I need to change between Windows directories and Linux ones, so I wanted to write a script that automatically converts a Windows path into a Linux path and then changes directories. I wrote the conversion script just fine, but for some reason I can't pass the path to cd.

Example:

```
$ mkdir temp\ space
$ temp=$(echo "temp\ space") # simulate script that converts path
$ echo $temp
temp\ space
$ cd $temp
-bash: cd: temp\: No such file or directory
```

Edit:

In hind sight I realized the this actually wasn't my problem, I must have been tired when I wrote this and introduce this bug into my minimal example. My real problem was that I didn't know [how to run a shell script in the current shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744904/how-to-execute-script-in-the-current-shell-on-linux) instead of a subshell. Thank you everyone for your help!

Comment: [Always quote variables](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you quote the string, `""`, you're saying "Use this string".  There is no need to escape the space, because you've encapsulated your string with double-quotes.

When you're using the terminal, and you do *not* encapsulate the string in quotes, the terminal wants to see the space as a new argument, and gets confused.  Are you familiar with CSV files?  Think about a CSV file that has a comma found as part of one of the cell values.  In both cases, we need to make sure to clarify the [delimiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter).  While CSV files will use a comma, `bash` and programs often use spaces to delimit, or separate command line arguments and their values.

**So, you either need to quote your strings that contain spaces, or escape the spaces in the string; not both.**

Because of this, there are a lot of 'best practices' when using BASH variables.  For example, you'll [always want to surround them in quotes](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086), to workaround the exact issue you're experiencing:

```
mv thisFile My Space Directory/ # What moves where?
mv thisFile "My Space Directory/" # It is clear what to move where
mv thisFile My\ Space\ Directory/ # Again, clear to the computer
mv thisFile "${tmp}" # Be sure string is not escaped.
```

Typically, you'll only escape the spaces when you're interacting with the terminal directly, yourself, for things such as <kbd>Tab</kbd> completion or doing other manual adjustments.

Also, take note that bash treats `'` and `"` slightly differently, in that `'` will not allow expansion, while `"` will.  For example:

```
$ BANANA_COUNT=4
$ newVar1="We have this many bananas: ${BANANA_COUNT}"
$ newVar2='We have this many bananas: ${BANANA_COUNT}'
$ echo $newVar1
We have this many bananas: 4
$ echo $newVar2
We have this many bananas: ${BANANA_COUNT}
```

Comment: I had a variable with an absolute path containing spaces and was intrigued why it failed to expand well on the Shell. I had escaped the spaces in the path with backslash. This caused a problem when using `echo "$var"`. The trick was to remove the backslashes in the path for this to work. Your 4th solution in the move example helped me. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should use double-quotes `"` to surround files, folders or variables that contain special characters or whitespace.

From the example you provided, that would be as follows:

```
~$ mkdir "temp space"
~$ temp=$(echo "temp space")
~$ echo "$temp"
temp space
~$ cd "$temp"
temp space$
```